# How to use MPIR with Visual Studio?

Tags: installation, visual-studio, libraries, cryptography, gnumeric

I am an academic and I need to develop some numerical algorithms which require functions from a package called MPIR http://mpir.org/downloads.html. I downloaded the 3.0.0 version and I am trying to figure out how to use this with Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 7 professional. Is there a way to use mpir package with Visual Studio C/C++? Sections 2.4 and 2.5 in this document http://mpir.org/mpir-3.0.0.pdf seems relevant however does not help much.

Comment: You do understand it's written in ANSI C, right?

Comment: So I cannot use it with Visual Studio? Do I **have** to use cygwin?

Comment: I have updated version. I am really naive on this stuff. Usually I have done only elementary C programming from text.

Comment: You don't need to know C, to build a project in Visual Studio, and to compile it.

Comment: See instructions for compiling MPIR under Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733707/msvc-official-arbitrary-precision-library

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to use mpir package with Visual Studio 2017 C/C++?

Yes;  Of course you can.  You use it like any other C++ interfaces.

> All MPIR C language types and functions can be used in C++ programs,
>   since mpir.h has extern "C" qualifiers, but the class interface offers
>   overloaded functions and operators which may be more convenient. Due
>   to the implementation of this interface, a reasonably recent C++
>   compiler is required, one supporting namespaces, partial
>   specialization of templates and member templates. For GCC this means
>   version 2.91 or later.

[Source](http://mpir.org/mpir-3.0.0.pdf)

As for building it, you need the required MSVC++ installed on your system, but MPIR 3.0.0 specifically supports building it from Visual Studio 2017.  Which means the source code as the required [solution files](https://github.com/wbhart/mpir/tree/master/build.vc15).

Answer (score 1):

If you have `vcpkg` install it is real simple:

`m .\vcpkg install mpir mpir:x64-windows`

You get debug, release, `x32` and `x64` could not be easier. If you do not have `vcpkg` install you should here is a simple tutorial See the following **[instructions](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2020/01/26/getting-started-gsl-gnu-scientific-library-windows-macos-linux/)**:

My build looked like the following

```
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    mpir[core]:x64-windows
    mpir[core]:x86-windows
Starting package 1/2: mpir:x64-windows
Building package mpir[core]:x64-windows...
-- Downloading https://github.com/wbhart/mpir/archive/mpir-3.0.0.tar.gz...
-- Extracting source C:/DEV/vcpkg/downloads/wbhart-mpir-mpir-3.0.0.tar.gz
-- Applying patch enable-runtimelibrary-toggle.patch
-- Using source at C:/DEV/vcpkg/buildtrees/mpir/src/mpir-3.0.0-c9f63a8302
-- Building C:/DEV/vcpkg/buildtrees/mpir/x64-windows/build.vc14/dll_mpir_gc/dll_mpir_gc.vcxproj for Release
-- Building C:/DEV/vcpkg/buildtrees/mpir/x64-windows/build.vc14/dll_mpir_gc/dll_mpir_gc.vcxproj for Debug
-- Performing post-build validation
-- Performing post-build validation done
Building package mpir[core]:x64-windows... done
Installing package mpir[core]:x64-windows...
Installing package mpir[core]:x64-windows... done
Elapsed time for package mpir:x64-windows: 2.77 min
Starting package 2/2: mpir:x86-windows
Building package mpir[core]:x86-windows...
-- Using cached C:/DEV/vcpkg/downloads/wbhart-mpir-mpir-3.0.0.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/DEV/vcpkg/buildtrees/mpir/src/mpir-3.0.0-c9f63a8302
-- Building C:/DEV/vcpkg/buildtrees/mpir/x86-windows/build.vc14/dll_mpir_gc/dll_mpir_gc.vcxproj for Release
-- Building C:/DEV/vcpkg/buildtrees/mpir/x86-windows/build.vc14/dll_mpir_gc/dll_mpir_gc.vcxproj for Debug
-- Performing post-build validation
-- Performing post-build validation done
Building package mpir[core]:x86-windows... done
Installing package mpir[core]:x86-windows...
Installing package mpir[core]:x86-windows... done
Elapsed time for package mpir:x86-windows: 2.016 min

Total elapsed time: 4.786 min
```

Answer (score 0):

Page 18 of your manual says to open the unpacked solution
at `mpir/build.vc15/mpir.sln`
and compile the build that you would like to use.
There are various optimized builds, but I would start with the general
`dll_mpir_gc`.

This will create libraries. Find the folder that contains the generated `.lib`
files and add it to your project as described in
[.Lib Files as Linker Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx).

Comment: So you open mpir/build.vc15/mpir.sln in Visual Studio and compile with the file I have? Is that all there is to do?

Comment: Yes, seems so. There might also be `.h` header files whose folder also needs to be added to your project.